# Converting string concatenation with lambda to f strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, concatenation, f-string

I am trying to wrap my head around advanced usage of f strings in Python 3 and I can't seem to figure out their usage with lambda functions. For example, when you have string concatenation that uses lambda to define some of the values in the string how do you go about using f strings? Even more so when one of the values uses an if function to define the value.

For example, I have tried the following:

```py
        cmd_out = reduce(lambda acc, x: f'{acc} -v {x["Source"]}:{x["Destination"]}'
                         f'{(":ro" if not x["RW"] is True else " ")} {mounts}')
```

But this doesn't work.

This is the original with concatenation.

```py
cmd_out = reduce(lambda acc,x: acc + "-v " + x["Source"] + ":" + x["Destination"]+ (":ro" if not x["RW"] is True else "") + " ", mounts, "")
```

So rather than using the concatation I would like to be able to use f strings to simplify the process and reduce errors. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include `mounts` in the lambda expression, but that's what `reduce` is supposed to iterate over. I wouldn't use `reduce` here; use the `join` method instead.

```
cmd_out = " ".join(f'-v {x["Source"]}:{x["Destination"]}{"" if x["RW"] else ":ro"}'
                   for x in mounts)
```

Comment: okay but you have removed `acc` which is also a variable so my output here is missing that. I and I got that value using lambda which is no longer required with this form. Unless I have misunderstood

Comment: I fixed your code by removing the `.join`  and still using `lambda` like so: `cmd_out = reduce(lambda acc, x: f'{acc} -v {x["Source"]}:{x["Destination"]}{(" " if x["RW"] else ":ro ")}', mounts, "")`

Comment: "Fixed" isn't the word I would use. You are basically using `reduce` to reimplement `join`.

Comment: the problem of using `join` instead of `reduce` and `lambda` was that I ended missing a crucial variable in my output `acc` . `join` wasn't allowing its use.

Comment: `acc` is just the accumulated output of `reduce` from one iteration to the next. `join` doesn't need it, because it combines all the segments at once. Compare `' '.join(x for x in ["1", "2", "3"])` with `reduce(lambda acc, x: acc  + x + " ", ["1", "2", "3"], "")`; the only difference is `reduce` produces a trailing space that you either don't care about or need to remove.